# Trying to make an SMS Reminder Application

Tags: php, web-applications, sms

I am working on a web-application to make an SMS Reminder service, which takes various inputs from the user, like the user's name, his number, and the time he wants the reminder. The reminder is then sent through an SMS. I have the SMS Gateway part figured out for which I am using Zeep Mobile's API. I wanted to know how I can send an SMS on the time input by the user.

The database would have the user-id and the time, and I need to get my application to send an sms at the time. Any tutorials on similar lines would be great help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Is your server linux or windows?

Comment: You may already be considering this, but make sure you've got time zones handled. It would be useless if the user wanted an SMS at 9am and instead got one at 1pm because the server was in a different time zone.

Comment: And always so lovely daylight savings... ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say your reminder interval is 1 minute and you are deploying on Linux.

1) Set up a cron-job to check your database every minute for possible reminders

2) If there are reminders to be sent, execute your sending script.

3) Mark sent reminders with a status (or similar) so you don't send them again.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what server your application is deployed, you would need to run some kind of service that would run continuously and send SMS whenever one is due.

One note though, since repeated database access is costly, you may like to load up Reminders that would need to be sent in a short time. The database should be accesses periodically with a reasonable time interval.